# How to pass a structure variable within functions

Tags: c

I created a simple C program to display about a simple bank transaction on withdrawals and deposits. I created the variables using structure. But there is a problem in passing structure variables within functions as they are not passing the values from one function to another as well as to `main` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct Details{
    char name[100];
    char day[100];
    int openingbalance;
    int amount;
    int closingbalance;
}detail;


void InputDetails(detail customer){
    printf("Enter Customer name: ");
    scanf("%s",customer.name);
    printf("Enter the date: ");
    scanf("%s",customer.day);
    printf("Enter opening balance: ");
    scanf("%d",&customer.openingbalance);
}

void transaction(detail customerr, int money){
    int selection;
    printf("Opening balance = %d\n",customerr.openingbalance);
    printf("Select the transaction\n1.Withdrawal\n2.Deposit\n");
    scanf("%d",&selection);
    switch(selection){
    case 1:
        if(money > customerr.openingbalance){
            printf("No sufficient balance in the account to process the request\n");
            customerr.closingbalance = customerr.openingbalance;
    }
        else
            customerr.closingbalance = customerr.openingbalance - money;
        break;
    case 2:
        customerr.closingbalance = customerr.openingbalance + money;
    }
}

void main()
{
    detail client;
    int amount;
    InputDetails(client);
    printf("Enter the transaction amount: ");
    scanf("%d",&amount);
    transaction(client, amount);
    FILE *file1;
    file1 = fopen("Bank.txt","a+");
    printf("Name\tDate\tOpening Balance\tAmount Processed\tClosing Balance\n");
    printf("%s \t%s \t%d \t%d \t%d\n",client.name,client.day,client.openingbalance,amount,client.closingbalance);
    fprintf(file1,"%s \t%s \t%d \t%d \t%d\n",client.name,client.day,client.openingbalance,amount,client.closingbalance);
    fclose(file1);
}
```

In the output it displays a wrong amount rather the entered opening balance and all the other variables including `name` and `date`.

Comment: C passes by value. When you pass the struct to the function, it creates a copy of the struct. Changes to that copy don't affect the originals. You need to change your function to use a pointer to the struct, and pass a pointer to `client` to the function. Passing a struct by value is also more time- and memory-intensive.

Comment: or perhaps pass the `struct` back as the function return value. That's reasonably practical for a small `struct`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I wouldn't call over 200 bytes small. It's not massive in modern-day terms, but it's more data than I'd want to by copying every time.

Comment: @ThomasJager it was a general remark about what can be done after the `struct` is passed directly. By "small" I was thinking of something like a rectangle or a pixel `struct`.

Comment: [How to affect the same copy of a struct in C?](//stackoverflow.com/q/42917701)

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the struct by value, which creates a copy of it. Operations on the struct in the function don't affect the original variables.

Instead of doing that, you may want to pass a pointer to the variable to your functions.

To do that, you need to change your function signatures to use a pointer to `detail`:

```
void InputDetails(detail *customer)
```

```
void transaction(detail *customerr, int money)
```

Since you're using a pointer, you need to dereference it to access the actual data pointed to by the pointer.

For other variable types you'd use the `*` indirection unary operator to access the value, which you can also do with structs:

```
(*customerr).closingbalance = (*customerr).openingbalance - money;
```

This is ugly. Instead of having to do this, you can use the `->` operator, which is just a prettier way of doing the above:

```
customerr->closingbalance = customerr->openingbalance - money;
```

In your functions, you'd need to replace every use of the `.` operator on `customerr` with `->`.

Doing this will save both time and memory since you don't have to make a local copy of the struct, and your program can function correctly.

When you call your functions, you'd use the `&` unary operator to take obtain the address of the struct variable and pass that, instead of the entire struct itself:

```
InputDetails(&client);
```

```
transaction(&client, amount);
```

Comment: Ya that's working after passing through pointers. Thank you all responded to me as soon as possible and cleared my issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass an object of a structure by reference through using a pointer to the object if you want that the original object would be changed in the function.

For example the function `InputDetails` should be defined like

```
void InputDetails(detail *customer){
    printf("Enter Customer name: ");
    scanf("%s",customer->name);
    printf("Enter the date: ");
    scanf("%s",customer->day);
    printf("Enter opening balance: ");
    scanf("%d",&customer->openingbalance);
}
```

and called like

```
InputDetails(&client);
```

Comment: Ya that's working after passing through pointers. Thank you all responded to me as soon as possible and cleared my issue